# XSP.showDialog doesn't work in onStart event?

Tags: xpages

I have the following test XPage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:panel id="pagePanel">
        <xp:text escape="true" id="didThePageCompile">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var d = new Date();
return d.toLocaleString();}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dialog1"
                onStart="XSP.openDialog('#{id:dialog1}')" 
                onComplete="XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialog1}')">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var agent = database.getAgent("runLongTime");
var response = agent.run();

// var d = getComponent("dialog1"); 
// d.show();
}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xe:dialog id="dialog1" title="Test Dialog">This is a test dialog</xe:dialog></xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

The agent "runLongTime" just sleeps for 10 seconds. This works fine. When I click the button however the dialog box does not show up. I checked the source and it generates the correct code, and that code works when I manually put it into the console.

I don't get any errors and the agent executes fine. I've also tried changing the refreshId to "pagePanel", but still the same.

Comment: How about `refreshId="button1"`?

Comment: Doesn't do anything. I've changed the onStart, onComplete to alert('test'); and that works.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your agent `runLongTime`. If I comment agent code and call a simple `print` method, even then I am unable to open the dialog. I put in a simple `alert` after `XSP.openDialog` then in source code of my page (using Google Chrome developer tools) I can see the `div` tag of dialog box appearing, but it disappears after click OK on my alert box.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, I think you are trying to show user some kind of message while the processing happens in background. If that is what you are trying to achieve then you could try out [Standby Dialog Custom control](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control) or look at [this blog post](http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2011/get-progressbar-everytime-partialrefresh-fires).

Comment: Here is a sample just in case you haven't seen it: http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/xpages-tip-a-modal-waiting-dialog-for-background-processes..htm. This does not use XSP.openDialog.

Comment: If you have a long running server-side process and want to let your users know what the progress is, have a look at this demo: http://demo.linqed.eu/demo/progressBar.nsf

Comment: @MarkLeusink thanks I'll have a look at that as well.

Comment: Also thanks Naveen and @PanuHaaramo, I had read those links already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`XSP.openDialog()` and `XSP.closeDialog()` each trigger a partial refresh. The XPages client-side API includes logic for preventing multiple partial refresh operations from executing in parallel, which is likely preventing your dialog from displaying because by the time it attempts to run the refresh to show the dialog, it's already running your button event.

Add a JSON-RPC (called "Remote Services" in the control palette) to the page. Move your button's server event code to a method of the RPC. You can then change the button event to be purely client-side: call `XSP.openDialog()`, then call the RPC method and close the dialog in the onComplete of that method. This should prevent the race condition you're currently experiencing.

Comment: I will never understand why partial refreshs can not run parallel... In my apps I just reset the allowSubmit flag, and everything works fine w/o any problem.

Comment: Thanks. This sort of answers my question. It works in the Web, but XPiNC it seems to work on and off. I'm putting the close in the addCallback() function.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. If I can't figure why the XPiNC isn't working correctly I'll do up another question. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Ok I solved the XPiNC issue. I put the agent running code into the onShow of the dialog box.

Comment: Sven, I'm assuming the reason parallel is not allowed is to maintain validity of the view state. If both requests change the state of components, which would win?

Comment: XPages states are saved server side. That's why I cannot see that there is a "Win/Loose" problem. As long as the state of the components are not changed and/or different branches of the component tree will be refreshed, it doesn't matter. As far as I know is the JSF state problem a full refresh problem only.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see here, you are trying to open/close the same dialog.
Some days ago I got the same issue and wondered why this was not working.

Finally I checked the events and ended with the spectacular result that onStart and onComplete fired up almost parallel.

Maybe you could try to insert a timeout (window.timeout) before calling the XSP.closeDialog event.