# cannot open xe:dialog when using select2

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

In an app I use the xe:dialog control. Unfortunately after implementing the select2 library the code to open the dialog is no longer working:

```
<xp:panel tagName="div" id="datarow" styleClass="pic-item pic-backgr-size-cover">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="onclick">
            <xp:this.value>
                <![CDATA[XSP.openDialog("#{id:dialog1}");]]>
            </xp:this.value>
        </xp:attr>
```

I tried the suggestion to add XSP.allowSubmit() before the openDialog command but this has no effect.

([Bootstrap Select2 open a loading dialog onStart partial refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116118/bootstrap-select2-open-a-loading-dialog-onstart-partial-refresh))

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Minor unrelated suggestion: replace '<xp:panel tagName="div"' with '<xp:div' :-)

Comment: and you have fixed the amd loader so the page doesn't crash in domino 9?
http://xomino.com/2015/06/02/select2-v4-needs-amd-fixing-in-domino-r9-xpages/

Comment: @Per actually it is code from a colleague which I try to solve :-)

Comment: Then be a good colleague and change from xp:panel to xp:div :-) Using xp:panel instead of xp:div is primarily only necessary if you want to add a data source to the panel.

Comment: @Fredrik. I am using v4 with Domino 9 and do not see xpages crash...